# Than him or than he in this case?

Tags: pronouns, relative-pronouns, personal-pronouns

> The handsome young teacher fell into easy banter with his students, who were not much younger than **he/him**.

Should this use "he" or "him"?

Comment: It's an **object pronoun,** so you put **him.**

Answer (score 0):

The "this is he vs. this is him" debate rages on.  Meanwhile, though, this one is something a bit different.  I would say *he* here, and will disagree with Oshnaj.  The reason is that here you are actually saying that his students were not much older than he *was*, and leaving out the *was*.  Obviously, "not much older than him was" isn't correct.

For a more complete treatment of the subject, see [this.](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8353/me-versus-i)

Comment: Can you explain why you say "he"? Perhaps paraphrase what's in the link? In general, link-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).